# Await the completion of a for-loop

Tags: javascript, image, for-loop, callback, filereader

I am trying to write some React code that handles client uploading of files. I handle the image resizing in the frontend, hence I need to make use of `FileReader` to convert the `File` object into `base64` and subsequently into an `Image` to check the dimensions, via the callback function.

All the `console.log` inside the callback are correctly printed, but the final return value from `console.log(thumbnail_map_value)` is undefined. I think it has something to do with the order of function execution. `console.log(thumbnail_map_value)` was called first, followed by `console.log("Client code done execution");` and then the `console.log(output_url)` in the `forEach` call, which implies that `await generate_image_thumbnails(file, secure_url)` is not resolved first as I expected it to be. Does anyone know how to resolve `await generate_image_thumbnails(file, secure_url)` first so that `console.log(thumbnail_map_value)` returns non-null value?

Here is my code for reference.

```
//1. First function
export const create_media_map = async function(file) {
  try {
    //Some other code

    //file is a File object which a client app has uploaded

    //Async call
    const res_obj = await request.post(url)
      .field('upload_preset', upload_preset)
      .field('file', file);
    const res_body = res_obj.body;
    const public_id = res_body.public_id;
    const secure_url = res_body.secure_url;
    const media_object = {};

    console.log(secure_url);

    let thumbnail_map_value;
    let media_tags_value = [];

    if (file_type.includes(MEDIA_IMAGE_TYPE)) {
      //{s,m,l}
      thumbnail_map_value = await generate_image_thumbnails(file, secure_url);
      console.log(thumbnail_map_value); //First print: return undefined

      // More logic with secure_url after this comment

    } else {
      //Logic for video format

    }

    //some other logic


  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error with function: ${create_media_map.name}`,error);
  }
}



//Second function
export const generate_image_thumbnails = async function(file, original_url) {
  const url_obj = {};

  const fr = new FileReader;

  fr.onload = async function() { // file is loaded
    const img = new Image;

    img.onload = function() {
      console.log(img.width);
      console.log(img.height);

      const width = img.width;
      const height = img.height;
      const decider = Math.min(width,height);

      const all_sizes = [64, 128, 256];
      all_sizes.forEach((size) => {
        if (decider > size) {

          //Parsing logic to determine a value to string_type

          const query_string = `w_${size},h_${size}`;
          const output_url = create_query_url(original_url, query_string);
          console.log(output_url)//3rd Prints out correctly
          console.log(string_type);//small,medium or large
          url_obj[string_type] = output_url;
        }
      });

      return url_obj; //Returning undefined
    };

    img.src = fr.result;
    console.log("Client code done execution");//2nd

  };

  fr.readAsDataURL(file);


}

//Third function
export const create_query_url = function(original_url, query_string) {
  const right_half_no_slash = original_url.split("upload/").pop();
  const left_half_with_slash = original_url.replace(right_half_no_slash,"");

  return `${left_half_with_slash}${query_string}/${right_half_no_slash}`;
}
```

Comment: Try to change 
    "const url_obj = {};"
to  "let url_obj = {};"

Comment: Hey, I've tried that and it's not working, I think the order of execution matters here, not the definition of the constants.

Comment: why not `async` to the function `generate_image_thumbnails ` and then `await` on call?

Comment: @Greedo I have tried that suggestion too, but that does not fix the problem. Have updated the signature of the suggestion into the post